# What does this number mean on reddit?

Tags: reddit

Am reading [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/askteenboys/comments/hy7vs6/whats_your_rice_purity_score/) on Desktop web (Chrome, MacOS).

What does these `14M`, `16F` mean? "14 years old Male"?

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the `About Community` info (found at the top right corner of the page):

> r/AskTeenBoys is a subreddit to ask boys questions. Please add a user flair indicating your age and gender. If you cannot find your age and gender, message us for a custom flair.

Also in the wiki page [Assigning User Flair](https://www.reddit.com/r/askteenboys/wiki/user-flair) one finds:

> Everyone has to apply a user flair **according to their respective age
> and gender** before posting or commenting.
>
> The icon or text that appears next to people's usernames is called
> "user flair". Each subreddit has its own and it is set up by the mods.